# Selenium 2.53 not working on Firefox 49.0.2

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, selenium-firefoxdriver

Selenium : 2.53

Firefox : 49.0.2

Windows10 : 32bit

When I execute the selenium webdriver from eclipse get the following error "about:blank&utm_content=firstrun" in firefox

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. After searching net, I found some of the links where they suggest to downgrade the firefox version. I am using 43.0.1 but you may try 46.0 also.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium WebDriver no longer supports the default Firefox Driver. They are currently working on a new driver, called Marionette, for their new Gecko engine.

More details on Marionette you can find here: [Marionette](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette)

If you want to use the default driver, you should downgrade your Firefox. Version 45.0.1 works fine for me.